# sqlite returned: error code =1, msg = near "port": syntax error, HELP Please

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-intent, android-sqlite

kindly help, the error is "sqlite returned: error code =1, msg = near "port": syntax error, HELP Please":

this code stop my app forcefully, kindly help to correct the error.

```
public static String DATABASENAME = "ftpdb";
public static String FTPTABLE = "fAccounts";
public static String colId = "id";
public static String colNmae = "name";
public static String colUserName = "username";
public static String colPassword = "password";
public static String colPort = "port";
public static String colHost = "host";
private ArrayList<FTPModel> ftpList = new ArrayList<FTPModel>();
Context c;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASENAME, null, 33);
    c = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists ftpAccounts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "name" + " TEXT ," + "username" + " TEXT," + "password" + " TEXT)" + "port" + " TEXT)" + "host" + " TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + FTPTABLE );
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addProduct(FTPModel fm) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", fm.name);
    contentValues.put("username", fm.username);
    contentValues.put("password", fm.password);
    contentValues.put("port", fm.port);
    contentValues.put("host", fm.host); 

    db.insert("ftpAccounts", null, contentValues);
    db.close();

}


public void removeProduct(String name, String username, String password, String port, String host) {
    try {

        String[] args = { name };
        getWritableDatabase().delete("ftpAccounts", "name=?", args);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public ArrayList<FTPModel> getAccounts() {

    ftpList.clear();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ftpAccounts", null);
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                FTPModel item = new FTPModel();

                item.name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("name"));

                item.username = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("username"));

                item.password= cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("password"));

                item.port= cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("port"));

                item.host= cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("host"));

                ftpList.add(item);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return ftpList;
}
```

}

kindly help to correct the code, thanks alot

Comment: Why construct the string like this? `CREATE TABLE if not exists ftpAccounts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT ,username TEXT,password TEXT, port TEXT, host TEXT)` works fine. Ohh, and don't use `AUTOINCREMENT`, a simple `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is better. And `port TEXT`? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ***ever*** find yourself with an SQL syntax error, you should (temporarily) print it out somehow before executing it.

That will almost always tell you ***exactly*** where the problem lies. If you had done that to your query in this case, you would have seen something like:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists ftpAccounts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT ,username TEXT,password TEXT)port TEXT)host TEXT)
```

(and the slightly reformatted to make reading easier):

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists ftpAccounts(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT ,
    username TEXT,
    password TEXT)port TEXT)host TEXT)
```

See that now? It should be ***instantly*** recognisable where the problem lies. You have closing parentheses at the ends of the `password` and `port` column specifiers where commas should be.

---

And, just as an aside, I'm not entirely sure what you think you gain by concatenating all those strings. If you want readable code, that's a good enough reason for doing it but I would suggest that it's then better done as:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists ftpAccounts(" +
           "    id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
           "    name     TEXT," +
           "    username TEXT," +
           "    password TEXT," +
           "    port     TEXT," +
           "    host     TEXT)"
);
```

so you can see the statement components in easily distinguishable parts.

The other thing you may want to look at is the suitability of `port` as a textual item. It would probably be better stored as an integral type.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists ftpAccounts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "name" + " TEXT ," + "username" + " TEXT," + "password" + " TEXT)" + "port" + " TEXT)" + "host" + " TEXT)");
```

To this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists ftpAccounts(" + colId + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + colName + " TEXT ," + colUserName + " TEXT," + colPassword + " TEXT," + colPort + " TEXT," + colHost + " TEXT)");
```

You had a few extra parenthesis instead of commas.
Completely forgot you wanted to use variables for the names of the columns.